# filtering input from serial port data

Tags: python, regex, serial-port, input-filtering

I am very very new to Python and I could use your help.
I made a small program that reads an analog signal from the serial port and dumps it into a file. However, even though the reading is very precise, sometimes it dumps unnecessary/undetermined characters into the file:

This is a dump from a 500 line file; check the 2nd value:
466
þ466
466
466

So, basically the problem is I have no idea how to filter this input from the readings. I've been reading a bit from the documentation in the regular expressions section, but I can't properly handle/manipulate the result. As you can see the "purifystring" function is very incomplete...

```
import serial
import re

#this is the pain...
def purifystring(string):

    regobj = re.match("^([0-9]+)$")
    result = regobj.find(string)

#start monitoring on ttyACM0 at 9600 baudrate
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)

#the dump file
filename = 'output.txt'

#save data to file
f = open(filename, 'w')
counter = 0;
while counter < 500:

    analogvalue = ser.readline()

    #need to clean the input before writing to file...
    #purifystring(analogvalue)

    #output to console (debug)
    f.write(analogvalue)

    counter += 1

f.close()

print 'Written '+ str(counter)+' lines to '+filename;
```

So even though that may not be the best approach, I'm opened to suggestions. I am trying to make my output file to have a value per line ranging from 0 to 1023. The data I get from reading the serial is a string something like '812\n'.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the job in a simple way (ie without regular expression ;) ) try this :

```
def purifystring(string_to_analyze):    # string is a really bad variable name as it is a python module's name
   return "".join(digit for digit in string_to_analyze if digit.isdigit())
```

this way, you will filter only the digits of the received data. ([isdigit()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit))

Comment: Thanks! This cuts what I asked. 
However, if you don't mind, I'd like to break it down a bit more:
From what I read, you go through every digit of the input and match it vs isdigit(), then concatenate with the result to 'itself' right?
On the other hand, I forgot to mention, I can't just return the valid digit, as it must be a valid 'result'. 
To be more precise: I will generate a graph out of this data, so after trying what you said (which worked) I found some broken data values like 778, 778, 7780, 778 (check 3rd), which would probably be caused by filtering wrong input, like 778, 77ª8, 778?

Comment: @Tobias : when i try the isdigit() loop on the "77ª8", I obtain 778, not 7780, it should be something else, but it will be much more difficult to detect bad inputs if they are made of numbers too...